# Converting to and from Doubles and Strings independent of locale

Tags: android, string, double, locale

I'm having problems with users that have their locale settings set to non US countries getting errors when converting doubles to and from strings. So far I believe I have the correct way to convert the strings to doubles:

```
public double stringToDouble(String s){
        try {
            return NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).parse(s).doubleValue();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
```

That is taking the input from an EditText box and converting it to a double. However I'm having problems converting doubles back to strings for to populate other EditText boxes. Here is the code I'm using that users are reporting crashes:

```
public String doubleToString(double d, String pattern){

        DecimalFormat df =(DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        df.applyLocalizedPattern(pattern);

        return df.format(d);
    }
```

I use the pattern string based on the amount of decimal places the edit text box has, for example "#0.00"

I can't figure out what's causing the crashes, and I can't even test it myself because I don't have those locales on my devices.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but you can test this using other locales by setting the language/locale of an Android Emulator and running your app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Locale.US` instead of `Locale.getDefault`.  Your string representations of doubles obviously aren't intended for direct interfacing with humans, and therefore the current locale should definitely not affect their interpretation.